# How to send message to a chat with botframework?

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to get the bot (botframework in dotnet) to send message to a chat (msteams) where the app has previously been installed.

This code works fine to send message in a Team Channel (but not in a group chat).

When using it to send to a chat (i'm only giving the chat id instead channelId) I'm getting "Bad format of conversation ID" (BadRequest)

```
        public async Task PostMessageAsync(string message, string channelId)
        {
            var serviceUrl = "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/au/";
            
            var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                IsGroup = true,
                ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                {
                    Channel = new ChannelInfo(channelId),
                },
                Activity = MessageFactory.Text(message),
            };

            await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).CreateConversationAsync(_appSettings.Integrations.Teams.ClientId,
                    channelId, serviceUrl, "", conversationParameters, (_, _) => Task.CompletedTask, default);
        }
```

I believe I'm missing something but can't figure out what. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally been able to make it work. No need to create a conversation it already exists for both channel and chat. This code will work for both.

```
  public async Task PostMessageAsync(string message, string channelId)
        {
            var serviceUrl = "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/au/";

            var conversationReference = new ConversationReference
            {
                ServiceUrl = serviceUrl,
                ChannelId = "msteams",
                Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: channelId)
            };

            await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appSettings.Integrations.Teams.ClientId, conversationReference, (context, token) => context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(message), token), default);
        }
```